# Render WASM Graphics to Custom HTML Canvas

Tags: html, rust, webgl, webassembly, bevy

I have setup a WASM project using Rust and a game engine called Bevy to create graphics within a Svelte app. However, when I run the init() function generated by wasm-pack, it creates a canvas element for the graphics to be rendered into. Is there any way to make it render to a canvas I have created or to style the canvas it generates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to specify the canvas bevy should render to by setting the `WindowDescriptor`'s `canvas` field

[The docs say](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/window/struct.Window.html#method.canvas) "If set, this selector will be used to find a matching html canvas element, rather than creating a new one. [Uses the CSS selector format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)."

When you create the `WindowDescriptor` add the canvas selector as a field.

```
let window_descriptor = WindowDescriptor {
    canvas: "#mycanvas",
    ..default()
};
```